# EventHandler issue with dependency injection in MadelineProto

Tags: php, symfony

### Code Example

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

// ... (omitting namespace imports for brevity)

class BasicEventHandler extends SimpleEventHandler
{
    public const ADMIN = '@me';

    public function __construct(private \App\Repository\ProviderRepository $providerRepository) {}

    // ... (omitting other methods for brevity)

    #[Handler]
    public function handleMessage(Incoming&Message $message): void
    {
        $provider = $this->providerRepository->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
        // ...
    }
}

BasicEventHandler::startAndLoop('bot.madeline');
```

### Description

When using the `BasicEventHandler` class within my Symfony application, I have enabled dependency injection to provide a `ProviderRepository`. The injected repository is accessible and correctly instantiated within the constructor. However, a PHP error occurs when `handleMessage` is triggered by an incoming message, suggesting that the `ProviderRepository` has not been initialized. The error message is as follows:

```
Typed property App\Service\BasicEventHandler::$providerRepository must not be accessed before initialization
```

This issue seems to stem from the serialization behavior in the event-handling mechanism, which does not preserve the initialized state of dependencies.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Set up a Symfony application with dependency injection.
2. Define a `BasicEventHandler` service with a constructor that takes a `ProviderRepository`.
3. Inject the `ProviderRepository` via Symfony's dependency injection.
4. Start the `BasicEventHandler` loop using `startAndLoop`.
5. Send a message to the bot that triggers the `handleMessage` method.
6. Observe the PHP error indicating the uninitialized `ProviderRepository`.

### Expected Behavior

The expected behavior is for the `handleMessage` method to access the injected and initialized `ProviderRepository` to process the incoming message.

### Actual Behavior

An error is thrown indicating that the `providerRepository` property is being accessed before initialization, as though the property is not being serialized/deserialized along with the event handler's state.

### Additional Context

- Symfony version: [6.3]
- `danog/MadelineProto` version: [8.0@beta]
- PHP version: [8.1]

Is there a recommended approach to handling dependency injection within an event handler that participates in serialization? Alternatively, should dependencies be fetched in a different manner when handling incoming messages in this context?

---

Note that you may need to adjust the code example, Symfony version, PHP version, and other specific details to match your actual environment.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Set up a Symfony application with dependency injection.
2. Define a `BasicEventHandler` service with a constructor that takes a `ProviderRepository`.
3. Inject the `ProviderRepository` via Symfony's dependency injection.
4. Start the `BasicEventHandler` loop using `startAndLoop`.
5. Send a message to the bot that triggers the `handleMessage` method.
6. Observe the PHP error indicating the uninitialized `ProviderRepository`.

### Expected Behavior

The expected behavior is for the `handleMessage` method to access the injected and initialized `ProviderRepository` to process the incoming message.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of the library responded to [my GitHub issue](https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto/issues/1445#issuecomment-1851058799):

> MadelineProto is not integrated with symfony, even if integration has
> been requested by a few people and will be implemented once I have
> some more time.
>
> You can still easily use symfony's dependency injector by creating the
> ContainerBuilder and registering the yaml in onStart, or using another
> dependency injection library like php-di (still in onStart, not in the
> constructor).